# How to use mysql now() function in querydsl?

Tags: mysql, querydsl

Lets say I have a mySQL table artifact as follows:

> artifact_id         varchar(50)
>   locked_status       char(1)
>   valid_till          datetime

```
 Select artifact_id from artifact where locked_status='Y'
```

For the above query, I have the querydsl representation as:

```
SQLTemplates templates = new MySQLTemplates();
Configuration configuration = new Configuration(templates);
QArtifact artifact = new QArtifact("a");
SQLQuery<?> query = new SQLQuery<Void>(con, templates);
List<String> artifactIds = query.select(artifact.artifact_id)
            .from(artifact)
            .where(artifact.locked_status.eq("Y"))
            .fetch();
```

How can I represent the below query in querydsl?

```
Select artifact_id from artifact where locked_status='Y' and valid_till > now()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to add

```
.and(artifact.valid_till.after(new Date()))
```

But if you are picky about the `NOW` function to be called on the server you might go with this:

```
.and(artifact.valid_till.after(Expressions.currentTimestamp()))
```

You can browse the code to see how the `DateTimeExpression` returned by this helper is generated.

Comment: Getting this error - The method after(Timestamp) in the type TemporalExpression<Timestamp> is not applicable for the arguments (DateTimeExpression<Date>), when using the Expressions.currentTimestamp() option.

Comment: Ok, then try this: `DateTimeExpression.currentTimestamp(Timestamp.class)`. It's actually the same like the expression above under the hoods with another Class as parameter.